# Xtext assign object in xtext file

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext, metamodel, ecore

Trying to make a meta model for Mongoose and MondoDb, using metamodeling concepts, eclipse and xtext.

I am trying to assign object that i created in my test.mydsl  file to another object in the same file, but i get error in my test.mydsl file.

I am trying to assign created Schema(sc1) object to Collection(col) object, but currently getting an error

**error message**

> the feature 'validate' of
>   'paket.impl.NCollectionImpl@67d76e14{platform:/resource/test/classes/test.mydsl#//@collections.0}'
>   contains an unresolved proxy
>   'paket.impl.SchemaImpl@361d8284{platform:/resource/test/classes/test.mydsl#|0}'

**my grammar for Schema and Collection**

```
Schema returns Schema:
    {Schema}
    ('Schema' '<' Name=EString) '>'
    '{'
        (schemaExpression+=Expression ( "," schemaExpression+=Expression)*)?
        (verificationDocumentElement+=VerDocElement ( "," verificationDocumentElement+=VerDocElement)*)?
    '}';

NCollection returns NCollection:
    {NCollection}
    ('Collection' '<' Name=EString) ',' (validate=[Schema|EString])? '>'
    '{'
        (document+=Document ( "," document+=Document)*)?
    '}';
```

**my test.mydsl**

```
Database<db1>{

    Schema<sc1>{
        var ja=lp   
        ime:{
            type:String,
            min:123.0
        }

    }
    Collection<col, sc1> 
    {

    }
}
```

I tried all, but unsuccessful.

Any ideas what to do?

Thanks

EDIT:

Maybe I was not clear enough. The major problem is with "validate" attribute in NCollection rule. 
When I create my Schema object(sc1 in test.mydsl) and then try to pass it to Collection(col in test.mydsl) as a "sc1", the "validate" attribute cannot accept it like string, and I don't know how to pass it like Schema object.
I hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use `name=EString`instead of `Name=EString` as Xtext imposes a special default semantics for the attribute `name`. Also I recommend to look into the documentation.

Comment: Tnx for answer, but actually that works just fine. I have a problem with (validate=[Schema|EString]). As i post in test.mydsl file, when i try to pass sc1 as a parameter in Collection<col, sc1>, xtext can not pass this created  sc1 Schema object to validate attribute in Collection. I cannot simply pass sc1 as a Schema object, even validate can accept Schema and EString as well.

Comment: I understand you did try to use `'Schema' '<' name=EString` rather than `Name=EString`?

Comment: How does your definition of EString look like?

Comment: Defined like this: EString returns ecore::EString: STRING | ID;
terminal ID    : '^'?('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;
terminal STRING : 
   '"' ( '\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\'|'"') )* '"' |
   "'" ( '\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\'|"'") )* "'"

Comment: Did you register a value converter for EString that strips the quotes?

Comment: I didn't understand quite well. Can you give me an example of what do you mean?  You mean something like this: 'sc1' in test.mydsl?

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
validate=[Schema|EString]
```

says: I want a schema reference via a String, i.e. `"sc1"` instead of the name. Xtext doesn't know how to convert a string into a reference. Use this instead:

```
validate=[Schema]
```

which is short for

```
validate=[Schema|ID]
```

That will use the name of the `Schema` as reference. Note that you have to write

```
('Schema' '<' name=EString) '>'
```

i.e. lower case `name` to make it work. Xtext has special handling for properties called `name`.

Comment: Thank you so much for an answer.
 "Name" property is actually a derived property from parent abstract EClass called "NamedElement", and it serves me to give a name to my Schema.
And when write name instead of Name it returns me an error: Cannot find compatible feature name in sealed EClass Schema from imported package http://www.project.com/paket: The type 'Schema' does not have a feature 'name'.

Comment: I changed Name(i.e. upper case) into name(i.e. lower case) into a Schema definition, so role for Schema can look like: ('Schema' '<' name=EString) '>',  and now it works. Thank you for a help.